# How to edit filter in New Experience?

Tags: sharepoint-online, new-experience

I was testing out the New Experience and I deleted my filters! How can I get the filters back or edit filters if possible? Right now I'm having empty filters...

What setting should I look into?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a couple of ways of adding to the filter list.

one is by uploading or creating documents within the library. once over two it would automatically display default filters like "modified since" and "type".

You could also add your own filters by going to the library and selecting one of the field columns drop down -> click "filter by" -> enter the value you want to filter by related to the field and hit "apply". This custom filter would now display within the filters list at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: hah it isnt my site ;) its from msdn :) thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Any metadata navigation configured in classic lists/libraries will be automatically added to the filters pane for modern lists and libraries.

So, for your issue, you can go to Library Settings->Metadata navigation settings, in "Configure Key Filter", select the fields that you want to add under "Available Key Filter Fields" and click "Add". Then click OK.

After that, when you go to the library view in New Experience, the column will be shown in Filter pane.